# Laravel priority order of queue not working

Tags: laravel, queue

I have studied about the laravel queues from here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues.
I have a situtation that my project had no queues in particular, and only 'default' queue was running. Now I have two queues: JobA and JobB. And I want to set priority of JobB higher than JobA.

To attach the jobs with queues I have used:

```
->onQueue('jobA');
->onQueue('jobB');
```

In .env file I have added :

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

And in queue.php this is the code:

```
return [
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),
'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ]

],

'failed' => [
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

];

And after making these changes, I run these commands on the server:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=jobB,jobA
php artisan queue:restart
```

The first command runs all pending jobs from specified table (jobs table).
But now the new jobs which are getting created, how will I get to know that those are in my mentioned priority order? And also I checked in the database table (jobs table) still name of queue is appearing as default.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks